# Closest function in subspace

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that $g = (f,e_1)e_1 +...+ (f,e_n)e_n$, is the closest element to $f \in L^2$ in the subspace spanned by orthonormal $e_1,...,e_n$, where closest is referring to the metric induced by the $L^2$ norm.

I went about doing this by taking a generic function $h=b_1 e_1+...+b_n e_n$, and showing that for $\|h-f\|_2$ to be minimized, $b_k = (f,e_k)$.

$\|h-f\|_2 = \sqrt{\int (h-f)^2} = \sqrt{\int f^2   - 2hf + h^2} = \sqrt{\|f\|^2 - 2 \int \Sigma_{k=1}^{n}b_k f e_k + \Sigma_{k=1}^{n} b_k^2}$

$=\sqrt{\|f\|^2 - 2 \Sigma_{k=1}^{n}b_k \int f_k e_k +\Sigma_{k=1}^{n} b_k^2}=\sqrt{\|f\|^2 - 2 \Sigma_{k=1}^{n}b_k (f,e_k)+ \Sigma_{k=1}^{n} b_k^2}$

Now, I want to show that this expression is minimized when $b_k = (f,e_k)$.  I am tempted to think back to highschool calculus and take the derivative with respect to the vector $b$, set it to zero, and then solve, but that seems wrong.  Am I missing something obvious here?

---

While there are related questions to this one, none of them seem to have my answer, because they are for specific cases.  Please let me know if this seems to be duplicated.  Furthermore, none of them took my approach, and I would like to know how I can do it better.

Comment: Check your calculation. It's wrong. And square the whole thing from the scratch to avoid the root.

Comment: Show that f-g is orthogonal to each $e_i$ and hence orthogonal to g. What does that tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this is one way to go. A bit of advice:

1. I would recommend considering the square of the norm instead of the norm itself: the minimizer is, of course, the same, but you won't need to deal with square roots when differentiating.
2. Taking derivatives w.r.t. the individual $b_k$, you see that the extremum point is
   $$
   b_k=(f,e_k),
   $$
   which if what you wanted. **Excercise**:can you prove that the extremal point is indeed a minimum and not a maximum and/or just a zero of the derivative?
3. This approach actually doesn't rely on any particular properties of $L_2$ and would work for any other Hilbert space.